# Replace null values with other values using Python conditional

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes with different number of row. So, lets say:

```
df1 = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John','Micheal'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18, 23], 'HeightEach': [156, 167,149 , 151, 149]}  
df2 = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18], 'Height': [179, NaN,159 , NaN]}
```

The issue now is , I want to replace the null values in 'Height' column with the same value in df1. So far I only know how to replace NaN with 0 like below code:

```
 df1['Height'] = df1['Height'].replace(np.nan, 0)
```

However, i do not know how to replace the NaN with this condition:

- Replace NaN with same `height` in df1 if the name in df1 and df2 is same. I tried to do like simple code below well at least to get the data with the same name:

  df1['Height'] = df1["Name"] == df2["Name"]

However it returns this error:

[image]

Edit: dataset for both data is not same. So, I just want to save the NaN data and ignore the existing data in df2.

So, i've tried:

```
if df1["Name"] == df2["Name"]:
    result = df2.merge(df1, how='inner')
    result.loc[result['Height'].isna(), 'Height'] = result['HeightEach']
```

It throws error:

[image]

Comment: use `fillna('value')`

Comment: `df1['Height'][df1['Height'] == np.nan] = df2['Height']`. Might also need to `df1.set_index('Name')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left merge df2, and df1, then fill `NaN` values by `HeightEach`

```py
result = df2.merge(df1, how='left')
result.loc[result['Height'].isna(), 'Height'] = result['HeightEach']

     Name  Age  Height  HeightEach
0     Tom   20   156.0         156
1  Joseph   21   167.0         167
2   Krish   19   149.0         149
3    John   18   151.0         151
```

It may not work in cases when there isn't value in df1 for all values in df2, you may want to do inner merge first and fill the `NaN` values in that scenario.

```py
result = df2.merge(df1, how='inner')
result.loc[result['Height'].isna(), 'Height'] = result['HeightEach']

df2.append(result)[['Name', 'Age', 'Height']].drop_duplicates(keep='last').dropna()
     Name  Age  Height
0     Tom   20   156.0
1  Joseph   21   167.0
2   Krish   19   149.0
3    John   18   151.0
```